# Connections are hanging in CLOSE_WAIT even after successful shutdown of Camel context/ routes

Tags: solr, apache-camel

I have one question regarding Camel route shut down.

Below is the code snippet for the route -

```
 from("seda:" + this.getDumpIdentifier() + "_insertInSolr?concurrentConsumers=50&pollTimeout=1")
            // use streaming to increase index throughput
            .setHeader(SolrConstants.OPERATION, constant(SolrConstants.OPERATION_INSERT_STREAMING))
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
            // define solr endpoint and options
            .to("solr://" + this.getSolrEndPoint()
                    + "?defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost=50&maxTotalConnections=150&maxRetries=3&allowCompression=true")
            //
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Successfully indexed document ID=${header.DOCUMENT_ID}.")
            // end this route
            .end();
```

I m using org.apache.camel.main.Main to start the Camel context (this route).
On successful processing I m doing -   `camelMain.stop(); camelMain.shutdown();`

But after successful shutdown of the route I m still seeing TCP connections in CLOSE_WAIT state (from this Indexer application to solr server deployed on tomcat).

Some observations - 
1. In the log I m not able to see anything related to solr://" endpoint.
2. I m seeing successful graceful shutdown of the route in the log.   example :
"message Route: route6 shutdown complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[seda://eventIncr_insertInSolr?concurrentConsumers=100&pollTimeout=1]..."

Question -
Any idea why is the underlying implementation of solr:// not releasing connections even after route has terminated (camel context shut down)?

Comment: What Camel version do you use?

Comment: We are using Camel 2.9.2

Comment: @ClausIbsen I tried with camel **2.11.0**, but still I m seeing connections in CLOSE_WAIT. I did a quick test on my local machine also.. with only 1 document to index, I m seeing one connection getting created and left there in CLOSE_WAIT even after job completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug in camel-solr. The resources is not properly stopped when stopping the camel-solr component. I have logged a ticket
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6396

Comment: Thanks! I see the ticket is Resolved, can you please share the release version?

Comment: Fix Version/s:
2.11.1, 2.12.0